# Ошибка при работе asmx сервиса (невозможно сериализовать System.Web.HttpPostedFile)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, веб-служба

При попытке запустить asmx сервис и увидеть доступные методы выдает ошибку (подробнее на скринах). Файл WebService1.asmx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace StegoWebService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Сводное описание для WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Description = "Stego", Namespace = "https://stego.by/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // Чтобы разрешить вызывать веб-службу из скрипта с помощью ASP.NET AJAX, раскомментируйте следующую строку. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Привет всем!";
        }

        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public HttpPostedFile UploadFile(HttpPostedFile postedFile, String key, String message)
        {
            //HttpPostedFile responseFile;
            return postedFile;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Запуск сервиса]

Параметры IIS:
[image: Параметры IIS]

Параметры SSL:
[image: Параметры SSL]

Результат при попытке просмотреть wsdl:
[image: Результат при попытке просмотреть wsdl]

Содержимое Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <!-- limit post size to 10mb, query string to 256 chars, url to 1024 chars -->
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="256" maxUrl="1024" maxAllowedContentLength="104857600"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

Раньше все работало. Возможно проблема как то связана с отсутствием в обозревателе объектов конструктора:
[image: обозреватель объектов]

Но непонятно как его туда вернуть.
Добавил все скрины, которые могут хоть как-то помочь.
Может кто-то знает, что можно сделать.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: спасибо, подскажите какие есть нюансы при оформлении кода, потому что Stack Overflow так и не дал мне его добавить.

Comment: в правом верхнем углу поля для редактирования вопроса есть круглая кнопка со знаком вопроса.

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267724/why-xml-serializable-class-need-a-parameterless-constructor) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212051/c-sharp-serialize-a-class-without-a-parameterless-constructor).